# Commands not executing within .BAT if statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which will check for the CPU architecture (32 or 64 bit), and perform commands accordingly. It will locate specific folders and execute certain .exe files. My problem is that if I have one statement inside the if statements, eg. 'echo Some text', it will show fine, meaning that the checks for architecture are fine. But as soon as I have multiple commands inside my If statement, the batch file exits immediately. My code so far:

```
@echo off

SET "ARCH=x64" 
IF NOT EXIST "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" ( 
IF NOT DEFINED PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 SET "ARCH=x86" 
)
IF "%ARCH%"=="x64" (
    cd \
    cd Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows
    start /wait MySQLInstallerConsole community install server;5.6.26;x64:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=somepass -silent

    cd \
    cd Program Files (x86)\Location
    start /wait DatabaseConfig
  ) ELSE (
    cd \
    cd Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows
    start /wait MySQLInstallerConsole community install server;5.6.26;x86:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=somepass -silent

    cd \
    cd Program Files\Location
    start /wait DatabaseConfig
)

pause
```

If I have the commands run from outside an if statement on their own like below, it works fine.

```
cd \
cd Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows
start /wait MySQLInstallerConsole community install server;5.6.26;x64:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=somepass -silent

cd \
cd Program Files (x86)\Location
start /wait DatabaseConfig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the brackets in `Program Files (x86)` path.Closing bracket is taken as part of IF command.Try this (paths are in double quotes):

```
@echo off

SET "ARCH=x64" 
IF NOT EXIST "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" ( 
IF NOT DEFINED PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 SET "ARCH=x86" 
)
IF "%ARCH%"=="x64" (
    cd \

    cd "Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows"
    start /wait MySQLInstallerConsole community install server;5.6.26;x64:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=somepass -silent

    cd \
    cd "Program Files (x86)\Location"
    start /wait DatabaseConfig
  ) ELSE (
    cd \
    cd "Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows"
    start /wait MySQLInstallerConsole community install server;5.6.26;x86:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=somepass -silent

    cd \
    cd "Program Files\Location"
    start /wait DatabaseConfig
)

pause
```